# select query by range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Hi I want to select values from tables by passing two parameters like start and end ranges

How can i get it?

Ex:

```
sid     sname

s001    name1 
s002    name2
s003    name3 
s004    name4
s005    name5 
s006    name6
s007    name7 
s008    name8
s009    name9 
s0010   name10
```

here i want to pass two values like 3 and 5 so that my query will return results like

```
s003  name3
s004  name4
s005  name5
```

Thank you

Comment: What database are you working on?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have 2 columns namely 'sid', and 'sname', correct? Also, why are the sid's named s<n> instead of just <n>?

Comment: ya I'm using sql server 2005 only

Comment: such an easy concept: list all keys between "3 and 5", made so complicated and cumbersome by a bad string key design: prefix+number

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server, and assuming your columns are both VARCHAR, and your "sid" column is always "s00" + number, then you could do something like this:

```
declare @value1 int
declare @value2 int

set @value1 = 3
set @value2 = 5

select
  sid, sname
from
  (your table name)
where
  sid between 's00' + CAST(value1 AS VARCHAR(3)) AND
              's00' + CAST(value2 as VARCHAR(3))
```

Marc

UPDATE:
If your rule is that the "SID" columns is always just a single letter "s" (or something else) and then any number of digits (e.g. "s1", "s012", "s292929"), then this query would do the trick:

```
declare @value1 int
declare @value2 int

set @value1 = 12
set @value2 = 15

select
  sid, sname
from
  tbl2
where
  CAST(SUBSTRING(sid, 2, 999) AS INT) BETWEEN @value1 and @value2
```

Whatever your pattern and rule is - you can find a query that works - but you need to know what your data looks like and how to query it.

Comment: I'm not sure the values will be in sequential order like s001, s002 and s003 they may have like s012, s015, s020 like this. So will it work for me?

Comment: It depends. In your example, you have S0010, in your comment you have S012. If your sid column is always formatted as S00<number>, this query will work.

Comment: @nagu: well, there has to be SOME pattern or something in order to query - you can't query for something you don't know how it's going to look like.....

Comment: This query will work for anything that starts with "s00......." - if your values are different, you'll have to adapt the query. The query can't just magically **know** what your data looks like - you'll have to know that and apply that knowledge to how you query your data.

Comment: So is the rule that the "SID" field will always be a single "s" at the beginning and then only (three, four, possibly more) digits after that?